# Set backgound color on a specific cell of GridPane in JavaFX

Tags: java, css, javafx

I want to set background color on specific columns of specific rows of `GridPane` in JavaFX (see screenshot). Please describe how can i do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add a pane for the single cell and give background color for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something like on the picture, maybe the easiest approach if you add your entries as `TextArea` by setting the [row span](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#setRowSpan-javafx.scene.Node-java.lang.Integer-) on `Node`s, like:

```
grid.add(area, 1, 0);
GridPane.setRowSpan(textArea, 2);
```

Then you can set the CSS style of the `TextArea` by overwriting the default CSS with your own style.

*Default CSS to overwrite:*

```
.text-area {
    -fx-skin: "com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TextAreaSkin";
    -fx-background-color: -fx-shadow-highlight-color, -fx-text-box-border, -fx-control-inner-background;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1, 2;
    -fx-background-radius: 3, 2, 2;
    -fx-padding: 1;
    -fx-prompt-text-fill: derive(-fx-control-inner-background,-30%);
}

.text-area .scroll-pane {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

.text-area .content {
    -fx-padding: 3 5 3 5; 
    -fx-cursor: text;
}

.text-area:focused {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-focus-color, -fx-text-box-border, -fx-control-inner-background;
    -fx-background-insets: -0.4, 1, 2;
    -fx-background-radius: 3.4, 2, 2;
    -fx-prompt-text-fill: transparent;
}

.text-area:disabled {
    -fx-opacity: -fx-disabled-opacity;
}
```

Copy this to your CSS file, overwrite as you wish, then add the stylesheet to your control, by:

```
grid.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("nameofyourcssfile.css").toExternalForm());;
```

You can use whatever control you want to display one entry, the styling can be done the same way.